# Hadoop Streaming: How to parition output into subfolders?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop-streaming, hadoop2, hadoop-partitioning

To be specific, for example, given

```
hadoop jar hadoop-streaming.jar \
  -input myInputDirs \
  -output myOutputDir \
  -mapper /bin/cat \
  -reducer /usr/bin/wc
```

Where myInputDirs has a dated subfolder structure of

```
   input_dir/yyyy/mm/dd/part-*
```

I want myOutputDir has the same dated subfolder structure:

```
   output_dir/yyyy/mm/dd/part-*
```

Guess there should be an option to do this. Can "-partitioner" or any "-D" option make this?

Comment: you can use Hive Dynamic Partitions to create Folders Dynamically.

Comment: Hive Dynamic Partition has certain limitation. It will not work in this case. User needs to add partition through code. @ Osiris- Can you put more detail about your problem to understand your question more.

Comment: I think you can create the file inside the reduce function and Write on it (use the pure java or python code) without using Write() of hadoop but I didn't see before that we can perform a partition with a hole path like p1/p2/p3/part-* only outputdir/part-*